# Variable Length Array C++ Wrapper Container

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, boost, containers

Is there a *dynamic* variant to `boost::array` that use C99's *variable length array* (VLA) internally when available (GCC) and *heap-based* otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost::array` works based on a template parameter. Template parameters can't be runtime values. So no.

Also, VLAs only apply to arrays declared on the stack (`ObjType val[someInteger];`). They do not apply to arrays declared *within* objects (`struct ObjType { int val[someInteger]; };`. So even if a template parameter could be a runtime value, it wouldn't help you.

If you can't afford a heap allocation, just use a `std::vector` with an allocator that pulls from a "stack" of pre-allocated memory.

Comment: Does STL, Boost or other provide such a stack-like allocator or do I have to write it myself?

Comment: I believe the STL only provides `std::allocator`, which uses `new` and `delete`.  Boost does provide a few allocators, including a pooled memory allocator ( http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/pool/doc/html/index.html ) that may do what you want.  Otherwise, you're going to have to write it.